# How to scroll up and scroll down using TestCafe?

Tags: testing, scroll, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

How can I scroll up and scroll down using TestCafe?

I tried `window.scroll()`,
`window.scrollTo()`and throws an error window is not defined.

Answer (score 11):

**UPD:
In [v1.14.0](https://testcafe.io/403064/release-notes/framework/2021-4-7-testcafe-v1-14-0-released) and later versions, you can use the following scroll methods: [t.scroll](https://testcafe.io/documentation/403065/reference/test-api/testcontroller/scroll), [t.scrollBy](https://testcafe.io/documentation/403066/reference/test-api/testcontroller/scrollby), and [t.scrollIntoView](https://testcafe.io/documentation/403067/reference/test-api/testcontroller/scrollintoview).**

**Old answer:**

In your case, you can create your own [`ClientFunction`](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/obtaining-data-from-the-client/#creating-client-functions):

```js
import { ClientFunction } from 'testcafe';

fixture `Fixture`
    .page `https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe`;

const scroll = ClientFunction(function() {
    window.scrollBy(0,1500);
});

test(`test`, async t => {
    await scroll();
    await t.wait(1000);
});
```

The [`t.hover`](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/actions/hover.html) action example:

```js
// scroll to the "#some-element-scroll-to" element
await t.hover(Selector('#some-element-scroll-to'));
```

Comment: I tried both methods and doesn't work though I don't see any errors and the added steps went through while running the scripts. I am trying to scroll up in the same way as I use double fingers on the mac mousepad and scroll up.

Comment: see the executable example [here](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-examples/tree/master/examples/scroll)

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue on Mac and used following to scrollIntoView of a know element in the page.

```
import { ClientFunction, Selector } from 'testcafe';
const scrollIntoView = ClientFunction( (selector: Selector) => {
    const element = selector() as unknown as HTMLElement;
    element.scrollIntoView();
});
fixture`HTMLElement`
    .page('https://example.com');
test('Scroll element into view', async t => {
    const bottomOfPage = Selector('#bottom-div');
    await scrollIntoView(bottomOfPage);
});
```

Reference : [Type cast page elements](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402824/guides/concepts/typescript-and-coffeescript#type-cast-page-elements)

Answer (score 0):

testcafe 3.3.0 has already enabled the scroll natively if the element we are selecting and out of our viewport, for example if you have a dropdown and it opens at the bottom margin hiding some options or testcafe scrolls down to take one of them closing the dropdown, you just select an element below in the DOM and testcafe scrolls on it making so all items of dropwdon selectable, I show you an example of code(idNotVisible is element out viewport):

```
.typeText('#idNotVisible', 'John Smith')
```

or

```
.click('#idNotVisible')
```